# How to disable CoordinatorLayout for Snackbar and FAB animation in Android

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

I have `CoordinatorLayout` which wraps `FloatingActionButton` from `Design Support Library`, in my layout `FAB` has `margin_bottom` set to over `50dp` so I don't want 'CoordinatorLayout' to animate `FloatingActionButton` even higher when `SnackBar` appears, because it won't be covered anyway.

How I can disable `CoordinatorLayout` so it won't move `FloatingActionButton` when `SnackBar` appears?

Here is my code :

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(getView(), R.string.you_have_to_be_logged_in, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction(R.string.log_in, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        LogInDialog logInDialog = new LogInDialog();
                        logInDialog.show(ft, "LogInDialog");
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use custom CoordinatorLayout.Behavior

```
public class FloatingActionButtonBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {
    public FloatingActionButtonBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
        return !(dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout); // here is key idea
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
        float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
        child.setTranslationY(translationY);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use this Behavior in FloatingActionButton or in CoordinatorLayout ?

Comment: For anyone want to know where to set this custom behavior, you can set it to the `app:layout_behavior` attribute of the FloatingActionButton.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really want to achieve this goal you can remove FAB from Coordinator Layout and then it shouldn't animate at all.

Comment: I need `CoordinatorLayout` for my custom `ScrollingFabBehavior`.

Comment: How to place it out of the `CoordinatorLayout`? That element considers as the root element and anything outside of the root element is invalid to Android Studio